# Creating text file from excel row values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write code which creates the text file at the specified location and the input is cel value

```
Sub Create()

Dim myPathTo As String
myPathTo = "d:\users\"
Dim myFileSystemObject As Object
Set myFileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim fileOut As Object
Dim myFileName As String

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then
            myFileName = Cells(i, 4) & ".txt"
            Set fileOut = myFileSystemObject.opentextfile(myFileName, 8, True)
            fileOut.Write Cells(i, 8)
            fileOut.Close
        End If
    Next

Set myFileSystemObject = Nothing
Set fileOut = Nothing
End Sub
```

No error is shown. Don't understand why it is not working

Comment: Did you try debugging it using `F8`, and watch what's happening at each step ?

Comment: Is the file being written somewhere other than where you expect?  are you passing in just the filename, or a full path.  You don't seem to use `myPathTo` ?   `myFileName = myPathto & Cells(i, 4) & ".txt"`

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
Sub Create()

Dim myPathTo As String
myPathTo = "d:\users\"
Dim myFileSystemObject As Object
Set myFileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim fileOut As Object
Dim myFileName As String

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then
            myFileName = Cells(i, 4) & ".txt"
            Set fileOut = myFileSystemObject.OpenTextFile(myPathTo & myFileName, 8, True)
            fileOut.Write Cells(i, 8)
            fileOut.Close
        End If
    Next

Set myFileSystemObject = Nothing
Set fileOut = Nothing


End Sub
```

You were not using the Full Path to save the File. Now you will see all the text files in `D:\Users\`

Comment: @AhmedAU ... I tried the code in my system, and it's working smoothly. Beside there is a new file created for each cell. So that should be inside the loop.

Comment: @Avi ... Can you add the screenshot of sheet on which you are running this code ?

Comment: @Avi .. Good to know that it's Working. Accept it as answer :)